# centering grid while hiding column width without reserved space

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

I have a `Grid` with two columns. I want to hide the second column until some one click on a `Button` in the first column. Problems is:

if I set visibility to collapsed on the second column, this doesn't display the element, and do not reserve space for it in layout causing the grid to not center when the second column is visible.

If I set the visibility to hidden, this doesn't display the element, but reserve space for the element in layout causing it to center but show the reserved space which I don't want when column 1 is visible and column 2 is not.

I want something in-between. For example, show only first column and center whole grid. When column two is also shown, center the whole grid again.

Does this make sense?

`XAML`

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"  />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Label  Content="Show second column on grid" Width="300"
                FontStyle="Italic" 
                FontWeight="Bold"
                Grid.Column="0" 
                Grid.Row="0"
                HorizontalAlignment="center"
                Foreground="White"/>
    <Button Content="Click Me" 
                Width="75" 
                Margin="5" 
                Grid.Column="0" 
                Grid.Row="1" Click="Button_Click" />
    <StackPanel x:Name="showSecondColumn" 
                Grid.Column="1" 
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.RowSpan="2"
                Margin="5,0,0,0" 
                Orientation="Vertical" 
                Background="Red" Visibility="Collapsed">
        <Label Content="Second column is shown" 
               Background="Red" />
        <Label Content="Another item inside second column" 
               BorderBrush="Red" 
               BorderThickness="3" 
               Margin="0,5" 
               Background="White" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

`Code behind`

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    showSecondColumn.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about trying a different approach?
You can have two columns, one with `width="*"` (so that it occupies all the available space), and set the width for second column as `width="Auto"`.
Then in the second column, you can place your control/container with `visibility` set as `collapsed` by default. And on the button click, you can toggle it as required.

Comment: If it is possible, then can you share the code, so that it can be seen what actually you are trying.

Comment: Hi, i get now what exactly you are trying to do.
Just set `Width="Auto"` for both the columns, then it will be always centered.